# Passing params object[] through jQuery to C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, reflection, invoke

I am trying to pass a `params object[]` through a jQuery to a C# method. I'm using this to use the same method through jQuery calls, sending a string that would be the real method to call and the `params object[]` that is the parameters to this call, obviously the number of parameters is unknown since I don't know exactly what method would be call, here is the code on jQuery:

```
$('#selectComboBox').change(function () {
    var data = {
        'method': 'GetComboBoxValues',
        'arguments': $.param({ Id: this.value })
    };
    LoadComboBox('/Get/GetJsonResult', data, $('#destionationComboBox'))
})
```

The LoadComboBox function is a simple function that I centered to populate comboboxes:

```
function LoadComboBox(url, data, select) {
    select.empty();

    $.getJSON(url, data, function (a) {
        $(a).each(function () {
            $(document.createElement('option')).prop('value',this.Value).text(this.Text).appendTo(select);
        });
    });
}
```

My C# code is below:

```
public string GetJsonResult(string method, params object[] arguments)
{
    var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(method);

    var l = methodInfo.Invoke(this, arguments);

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(l);
}
```

I get arguments as a object array and it is filled with a string `Id=1` (with `$('#selectComboBox').value` being `1`). I was not able to perform a `Split('=')` in a new array because if the real method (`GetComboBoxValues`) is not expecting a string (in this case is a `INT`) it would not be dynamically converted.

Do anyone has any tips or clues?

Comment: What is `LoadComboBox`? What does your intermediate JSON look like currently? I don't understand your sentence: "I was not able to perform a Split('=') in a new array because if the real method (GetComboBoxValues) is not expecting a string (in this case is a INT) it would not be dynamically converted."

Comment: Sorry about the LoadComboBox function. I'll edit it to contain the function. But to summarize it's a function that load combo boxes based on the three parameters: method that you want to call, parameters for that, and the html select element that will be populated.

Comment: The Split sentence basically shows a way that I tried to make it happen that didn't work. I thought that if I split the arguments into a new array would work because it would index the parameters, it actually pass the parameters correctly, but when the real method has a parameter that isn't a string, it fails because cannot be implicity converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a really interesting question. It seems like your main issue is dynamically converting from an object array to a bunch of required parameter types of a dynamically selected method. In short, this can be done using `methodInfo.GetParameters();` and using `Convert.ChangeType` to convert each of your arguments into the appropriate `ParameterType`. This is probably best seen in action, so I made a small Forms app that does this. Of course, this all makes a ton of assumptions that what is passed in will be "clean" so a lot of error handling is probably in order.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //mock up some dynamically passed in parameters
    var testParams = new List<object>();
    testParams.Add("1");
    testParams.Add("Hello");

    //the args I'm building up to pass to my dynamically chosen method
    var myArgs = new List<object>();

    //reflection to get the method
    var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("test");
    var methodParams = methodInfo.GetParameters();

    //loop through teh dynamic parameters, change them to the type of the method parameters, add them to myArgs
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var p in methodParams)
    {
        myArgs.Add(Convert.ChangeType(testParams[i], p.ParameterType));
        i++;
    }

    //invoke method
    var ans = methodInfo.Invoke(this, myArgs.ToArray());

    //display answer
    MessageBox.Show((string)ans);
}

public string test(int i, string s)
{
    return s + i.ToString();
}
```

As an aside, in my opinion, this leads to some crazy code that's tough to maintain (you're trying to do things with C# that it wasn't really meant to do). But you didn't really ask anyone's opinion, so I'll leave that as an aside.

Comment: Man thanks! As you said, I need to make some adjustments to that, especially when the parameter is a Nullable type, but was your idea that lead me to it. I'll post the method with your idea and my adjusts.

Comment: To address your opinion, I'm trying to work on stuff that shouldn't be maintained, this is a method that will be called and will return what you're looking for, if it doens't work, probably there is something wrong with jQuery function or even the real method that is calling, theoretically, of course. Do you think it's wrong, or do you have any advice?

Comment: It looks like you're basically trying to recreate what ASP.NET Web API already does. Instead of passing the method name as a parameter, you could explicitly route your methods to different URLs and have the methodName be part of the URL instead of a parameter to a method. Web API will also take care of all the type conversion for you, and return some moderately intelligent error messages if the request is not valid. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: I understand, also very valid approach.But another thing to consider is that I would need to create methods for each json call too. In my way I just have one method for each entity's call with a list returning, and then a generic method that converts the list to json, in this way I don't need to create a method for each entity's combobox call. Hope I made myself understandable with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Bell lead me to the answer, his idea just needed some adjusments, commented below, the answer was on editing the GetJsonResult method, to this:

```
public string GetJsonResult(string method, params object[] arguments)
{
    var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(method);
    var methodParameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

    var parameters = new List<object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; i++)
    {
        //  Here I'm getting the parameter name and value that was sent
        //  on the arguments array, we need to assume that every
        //  argument will come as 'parameterName=parameterValue'
        var pName = arguments[i].ToString().Split('=')[0];
        var pValue = arguments[i].ToString().Split('=')[1];

        //  This way I can get the exact type for the argument name that I'm sending.
        var pInfo = methodParameters.First(x => x.Name == pName);

        parameters.Add(Convert.ChangeType(pValue,
            //  This is needed because we may be sending a parameter that is Nullable.
            Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pInfo.ParameterType) ?? pInfo.ParameterType));
    }

    var l = methodInfo.Invoke(this, parameters.ToArray());

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(l);
}
```